# How do I access a column in the association table?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I have a many to many association

```
articles *---* categories via article_categories
```

This is what article_categories looks like 
      id
      article_id
      category_id

Now I added another column to article_categories called 'score'

```
  id
  article_id
  category_id
  score
```

Here is how I have written out the categories

```
 foreach ($article->categories as $c) {
      echo $c->title     
 }
```

I want to output the article_category score along side the category title. How do I do that?

But I also need to output the score along with the title

```
 foreach ($article->categories as $c) {
      echo $c->title
      echo $c->  ?     # how do I do this here?
 }
```

Comment: var_dump( $article ); just before the foreach.  post the output

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the 'score' is an attribute of the relation, NOT of the category. 
So your tables make perfect sense, but the code needs a slightly different approach.

Define your relations to both categories and article_categories, something like:

```
Article extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $has_many = array(
        array('article_categories', 'class_name'=>'ArticleCategory') // php-AR's pluralization won't work by default
        array('categories', 'through' => 'article_categories'),
    );
}

ArticleCategory extends ActiveRecord\Model {
    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('article'),
        array('category'),
    );
}

// So for simple and direct access to the category and its attributes you can do:
foreach ($article->categories as $c) {
    echo $c->title;
}
// To also get the score you have to: 
foreach ($article->article_categories as $ac) {
    echo $ac->category->title;
    echo $ac->score;
}
```